# regular expression with negative matching

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to do a regular expression to get the comment.

I want to distinguish of single comment `/*afdafad */` and multiple comment `/* appple .......`

Single comment is ok, but I am confused with multiple line comment.

I tried this:

```
set line "/* using cmos4 delaymodel */"
regexp {\/\*.+[^*][^/]} $line
puts [regexp -inline {\/\*.*[^\*][^/]} $line]
```

Output:

```
{/* using cmos4 delaymodel *}
```

I can't escape the `*` symbol.

I expect that, I should match the line which is contain `/*` but no  `*/` in the `$line` but I failed, so that how could I modify my regular expression?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would go to your previous questions and give feedback on the answers you were given. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for reference of how to use the site when you get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is not an answer to the regex-centric question. I just wanted to point out that in Tcl, you do not have to resort to a regex in your particular case (esp. if you assume your commented sources being well-formed etc.).

### Suggestion

You may want consider an exercise of textual polishing, i.e., pre-processing your commented source into a source containing Tcl command sequences: `[cmd ...]`. In your case, delimiters opening and closing comments, respectively, turn into opening and closing brackets of a command sequence. The command executed could be a proc such as `comment` below, capturing and further handling your comment bodies or returning a placeholder into the processed text. Actual command execution (that is, comment capture) is then triggered by applying [subst] on the preformatted source.

Watch:

```
set input {/* this is a
    multiline comment */ /* This is a [single line] comment */}

proc comment {body} {
    puts "got a comment: '$body'"
    return "/* ---%<--- */"
}

set tmp [string map {"[" "\[" "]" "\]" "/*" "[comment {" "*/" "}]"} $input]

set output [subst -novariables -nobackslashes $tmp]
```

### Comments

- Obviously, this gives you no direct means to validate the use of comment syntax etc. Either you are in a position to assume valid syntax use or, alternatively, you may check the pre-formatted Tcl string to be a complete Tcl script: `[info complete $tmp]`. This will only catch certain occurrences of unbalanced brackets (comment delimiters), though.
- The discrimination between single-line vs. multi-line comments is not critical for capturing comments.
- Depending on the source syntax, you would have to protect characters that could be misinterpreted as Tcl syntax during `[subst]`. E.g., brackets as genuine syntax elements or $. This must be controlled for using escapes using `[string map]` and restrictions to `[subst]` (`-novariables`, `-nobackslashes`).

Comment: You'll have to be especially careful if the original input contains mismatched braces.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because while `[^\*]` doesn't accept the `*`, `[^/]` will. The engine solves the match by letting `[^\*]` consume the blank before the `*`.

If you do

```
regexp -inline {(/\*.*)\*/} $line
```

you get

```
{/* using cmos4 delaymodel */} {/* using cmos4 delaymodel }
```

This is probably the easiest. You can get the capture by either one of

```
lindex [regexp -inline {(/\*.*)\*/} $line] 1
regexp {(/\*.*)\*/} $line -> a
```

In the latter case, the variable `->` gets the full match and `a` gets the capture.

If the comments don't contain any asterisks, you could also use the regex `/\*[^*]*`, i.e. match everything from a comment start up to but not including the first asterisk.

(And you don't need to escape slashes in Tcl regexes, they are slash-friendly.)

Comment: thanks a lot , but why "(/\*.*)", can we just use /\*.* without "()" ?   => regexp -inline {/\\*.*[^\\*/]}

Comment: @pilistar0222: mainly because in that case even a space or a newline after the comment end means that the comment end marker becomes part of the match. But if it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you are matching the regex against doesn't contain irregularities such as strings like look like comments (e.g. in JavaScript something like `var s = '/* incorrect comment */'`), and that you are not too familiar with Tcl's regexp, then the chances are pretty high that your method to distinguish single comments might also be wrong. This is because by default, `.` in Tcl's regex matches newlines.

Thus for single line comments only, you might need something like:

```
regexp -linestop -inline -- {/\*.*\*/} $line
```

Without `-linestop`, the above will be able to match both single line comments and multi line comments.

And for multiline comments only, something like the below to force a newline inside the comment:

```
regexp -linestop -inline -- {/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^/])*?(?:[\r\n]+.*?)+\*/} $comment
```

Note: the second `.*` being lazy of the `+` being greedy have no impact on the regex here because all these are lazy due to the first quantifier being lazy. I made the second `.*` lazy because to me it looks a bit more explicit that this one absolutely needs to be lazy. The edge case it takes care of is something like this:

```
/* this is a
   multiline comment */ /* This is a single line comment */
```

Comment: adding the explicit newliines isn't necessary, I think: `regexp -all -inline  {/\*(.*?)\*/} $input` -- or `foreach {match comment} [regexp -all -inline  {/\*(.*?)\*/} $input] {puts "found comment: >>>$comment<<<"}`

Comment: @glennjackman The problem I understood was that single comments and multiline comments have to be matched separately. The expression you provide would match both. I can't think of anything else if the OP wants to negate `*/` on the same line.